# Labels alignment behaves weird

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx

I have a panel that contains two labels. Such panels are used in a statistics block as "name:value". But name's length is different for every entry and UI looks ugly at the end. I decided to get the size of the biggest label and set `setPrefWidth()` for all labels in the column to that size. But UI starts looking weird at the end.

Here is what I have:

[image]

Here is the code of such panel:

```
public class StatLine extends HBox {
    private Label name;
    private Label value;

    public StatLine(String name) {
        super();
        this.name = new Label(name);
        this.value = new Label("99999");

        this.name.setPrefWidth(25);

        this.getChildren().addAll(this.name, this.value);
    }
}
```

Without `setPrefWidth()`, my result now is the following:

```
Name1: 99999     Name3: 99999
Long Name: 99999 Name31: 99999
Name2: 99999     Longest3: 99999
```

The result I want to get at the end:

```
Name1:     99999   Name3:    99999
Long Name: 99999   Name31:   99999
Name2:     99999   Longest3: 99999
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [GridPane](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/layout/GridPane.html) to lay out the data like a table. This will automatically adjust the cell widths to match the longest field.

Comment: Thanks, I forgot about this layout :)